React Router intercepting CloudFront static files causing 404 errors
I've got a React app hosted on an S3 Bucket with CloudFront and I'm wanting to have a HTML file play a video (embedded player as an IFrame).
I've setup the CloudFront distribution with a behavior specifically for the /videos/* path pattern that forwards the request to the S3 bucket without involving the React app.

In the html file if I try and serve the video from the CloudFront Distribution or the Domain it fails with a 403:
<video id="videoPlayer" controls>
...
videoPlayer.src = `https://d1jk10eqart123.cloudfront.net/videos/${videoFilename}`;

When I put the url into a browser it gives me the 404 NotFoundPage, hence I know it's not bypassing the React apps Routes and the NotFoundPage catch-all is being returned.
 <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />

Serving from a different url does work:
//videoPlayer.src = `https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sydney123.com/videos/${videoFilename}`;

I should mention I have other files, PDFs and other files that download perfect from the CloudFront Distribution and Domain, but these mkv and mp4s won't download (with Content-Type's set appropriately), they go through the Routing and give a 404. Also note without the Behavior /videos/* the same issue occurs. What might be happening here?

For anyone reading this who is in a similar situation, there is a solution but its a hassle. If you make a subdomain eg assets.yourdomain.com and put all your images, vids, css, etc in the subdomain  bucket and establish a Cloud Front Distribution for the subdomain. Then you can put your Index.html and JS files in the yourdomain.com bucket and have updates apply instantly and get around this issue where you need to specify another domain for assets/resources - for whatever reason.
